# Can not print on same line in python. Neither print("string here", end = "") nor does print "something", work

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want to print multiple statements on the same line in python 3.7. I have tried both using the `print " string"`, and `print("Something",end = " ")` but neither work. Both give syntax errors.

```
print 'Checkout: ',
```

Gives

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('Checkout: ', end=" ")
```

Ironically when using:

```
print('Checkout: ', end = " ")
```

I get a red line under the = " " part saying `unexpected expression syntax.`

Edit: The problem was that the IDE was essentially running in 2.* mode. Even though there was a red line under the end = " " part it compiled and ran fine.

Comment: 1/ Are you sure that you are effectively running Python 3.7? You can check with `import sys; print(sys.version)`. 2/ Please paste the **exact** error message you get when trying to run each version of the code.

Comment: You seem to be running Python 3 with your IDE set to Python 2 mode.

Comment: I checked the version. It is 3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43)

Comment: So the red line just comes from your editor that isn't aware of the new syntax in Python3, that won't prevent your code to execute. Just don't worry about it, or see if you can configure or update it for Python3 - or get another editor!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Any idea how to fix it (i am using pycharm and think it causing all kinds of trouble, like debugger not working)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Python 3.* the `print "Checkout"` isn't going to work because Python 3.* requires the parenthesis. If you would like to print multiple statements on the same line you could try something like this,

```
 print("Checkout: , Tax: , Balance: ")
```

If you are interested in placing values in the blank spots then, perhaps you could try this,

```
 print("Checkout: {0}, Tax: {1}, Balance: {2}".format(100, 0.8, 100.8))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I need to print checkout, and then loop through a list that constantly changes size.

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: You can try
     list = ['Apple', 'Banana']
     print("Checkout: ", *list)

Comment: Or explicitly `for item in list: 
 print("Checkout: {0}".format(item))`